# laggy bluetooth mouse logitech M585/M590

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech

Does anyone else have a laggy mouse when connecting the mouse normally via the bluetooth settings? It used to work fine for me until some updates a while ago. Now I have to use the Logitech Unifying Receiver which is annoying. Under Fedora Gnome this did not happen, only under the most recent Ubuntu and Debian 10 stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Following [Annatar's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1180286) in [Bluetooth mouse is laggy (low poll rate...) in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133018/bluetooth-mouse-is-laggy-low-poll-rate-in-18-04) worked for me:

1. Edit the following file:

   ```
   sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/xx\:xx\:xx\:xx\:xx\:xx/yy\:yy\:yy\:yy\:yy\:yy/info
   ```

   where `xx:xx....` is the Bluetooth address of the PC and `yy:yy...` is the Bluetooth address of the mouse.
2. In the file, add this section at the end:

   ```
   [ConnectionParameters]
   MinInterval=6
   MaxInterval=7
   Latency=0
   Timeout=216
   ```
3. Then, restart the Bluetooth service with:

   ```
   systemctl restart bluetooth
   ```